# How to properly save data to database with AXIOS

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, database, asp.net-core

I am trying to save data do database throught React.js and Axios library, but I cannot save them, still getting `Request failed with status code 400`. It is for the first time I am using react and database in `ASP.NET Core`. My goal is to create Scheduler with events and `CRUD` operations. I also setted up proxy route and in AppRoutes.

Model:

`public class EventDto     {         public string Description { get; set; }         public DateTime Date { get; set; }     }`

**React Component:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import axios from 'axios';

function FullComponent() {
    const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

    const handleDateClick = (arg) => {
        const newEvent = {
            Desctription:'Desctiprion', 
            date: arg.date
        };
        axios.post('/api/events', newEvent)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                setEvents([...events, newEvent]);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };


   

    return (
        <FullCalendar
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
            initialView="dayGridMonth"
            dateClick={handleDateClick}
            events={events}
        />
    );
}
export default FullComponent;
```

**Controller:**

```
 [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class EventController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public EventController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/api/events")]
        public IActionResult Post(EventDto eventData)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Omega_Conn")))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    string query = "INSERT INTO Event_Test (Description, Date) VALUES (@description, @date)";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", eventData.Description);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", eventData.Date);
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // log the exception or return an error response
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

setupProxy.js:

```
const context =  [
  "/api/events",
];

module.exports = function(app) {
  const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  });
```

Entity in Db is simple. I want to store Desctription and Date.

Comment: are your api and site running under the same port?

Comment: `const newEvent = {
            Desctription:'Desctiprion', 
            date: arg.date
        };` you have a typo here... According to your model it should be Description and Date. Not Desctription.

Comment: Before trying to hit your api endpoint through JS code, you might find it easier to test your api with a tool like Postman. That way you can make sure the api is working as itended.

Comment: have you tried with public IActionResult Post([FromForm]EventDto eventData) ?